# Robotframework: Keep on refreshing browser page until page contains the element

Tags: selenium, robotframework

With Robot Framework and Selenium, I want to create a keyword to keep on refreshing the page until page contains the element.
I do not think I can use `Wait Until Page Contains Element  <xpath>  <time>` because the page needs to be refreshed to show the element.
How can I write a FOR Loop to do this?

```
*** Keywords ***
Refresh Page until page contains the element
     Reload Page
     Page Should Contain Element  <xpath>
```

Or may be I can somehow loop this?

```
${Reload}=  Run Keyword And Return Status  Page Should Contain Element  <xpath>
Run Keyword If    ${Reload}  <don't know how to write here>    ELSE    Reload Page
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this could be achieved by using something similar to the below snippet. Using a while loop which has additional examples here: [RoboCorp WHILE Loops](https://robocorp.com/docs/languages-and-frameworks/robot-framework/while-loops)

```html
Refresh Page Until Page Contains Element
    ${Reload}=  Run Keyword And Return Status  Page Should Contain Element  <xpath>
    WHILE    ${Reload} != ${TRUE}
        ${Reload}=  Run Keyword And Return Status  Page Should Contain Element  <xpath>
    END
```

Hope this helps